# Kendo window clear inputs and validation messages

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

We use Kendo for ASP MVC and use lots of reusable Kendo windows with inputs, grid etc. in them.
Everytime we use reusable window we have to manually clear validation messages, inputs and grid on window open/close.
Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: Destroy the window after closing it, so next open() will recreate the window from it's original state.

Comment: you can have a generic function to clear all inputs form without clearing them one by one, for ex: $('[name]').each(function () {
        var elt = $(this);
        var widget = kendo.widgetInstance(elt);
        if (widget && typeof widget.readonly === "function") {
            widget.value('');
        }
        else
            elt.val('');
    });